# Variable not becoming a series of values. Why?

Tags: global-variables, pine-script, series

I created this script to detect Swing Highs and Lows and then to determine the High and Low values of these Swings.   The code works for the last bar, but I would like these values to be a series I can refer back to, but it's not.   It's just retaining the last value.   Not sure why.  I included a picture of the indicator that includes this codeand a table in the corner with the last 5 swing high values....as you can see there are different swing highs but the same value in the table. Here is the code:

```
//Swing Highs and Lows
swing_detection(index)=>
    swing_high = false
    swing_low = false
    start = (index*2) - 1 // -1 so we have an even number of
    swing_point_high = high[index]
    swing_point_low = low[index]
    
    //Swing Highs
    for i = 0 to start
        swing_high := true
        if i < index 
            if high[i] > swing_point_high 
                swing_high := false
                break
        // Have to do checks before pivot and after seperately because we can get
        // two highs of the same value in a row. Notice the > and >= difference
        if i > index
            if high[i] >= swing_point_high 
                swing_high := false
                break
        
    //Swing lows
    for i = 0 to start
        swing_low := true
        if i < index
            if low[i] < swing_point_low 
                swing_low := false
                break  
        // Have to do checks before pivot and after seperately because we can get
        // two lows of the same value in a row. Notice the > and >= difference
        if i > index
            if low[i] <= swing_point_low 
                swing_low := false
                break 
        
    [swing_high, swing_low]

// Check for a swing
[swing_high, swing_low] = swing_detection(barsback)

//Determine Swing High and Low Values

var float swing_high_price = na
var float swing_low_price = na
 
if swing_high
    swing_high_price := high[barsback] 
if swing_low
    swing_low_price := low[barsback]
```

[Example of indicator with this code in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ffHx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code that explicitly builds a series/array so I suppose you expect `swing_high_price` to be the series as you add value bar-by-bar (built by the Pine engine automatically).

However Variables defined with `var` needs to be handled with care or you will put gaps into their series, on which Pine usually barfs.

Instead of the IF structure at the end, try this:

```
swing_high_price := swing_high ? high[barsback] : swing_high_price
```

That is, `swing_high_price` will be always set on every bar. This will result in a continuous series, which keeps Pine happy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.   I got it working creating a function using valuewhen().

```
//Swing Highs and Lows
swing_detection(index)=>
    swing_high = false
    swing_low = false
    start = (index*2) - 1 // -1 so we have an even number of
    swing_point_high = high[index]
    swing_point_low = low[index]
    
    //Swing Highs
    for i = 0 to start
        swing_high := true
        if i < index 
            if high[i] > swing_point_high 
                swing_high := false
                break
        // Have to do checks before pivot and after seperately because we can get
        // two highs of the same value in a row. Notice the > and >= difference
        if i > index
            if high[i] >= swing_point_high 
                swing_high := false
                break
        
    //Swing lows
    for i = 0 to start
        swing_low := true
        if i < index
            if low[i] < swing_point_low 
                swing_low := false
                break  
        // Have to do checks before pivot and after seperately because we can get
        // two lows of the same value in a row. Notice the > and >= difference
        if i > index
            if low[i] <= swing_point_low 
                swing_low := false
                break 
        
    [swing_high, swing_low]

// Check for a swing
[swing_high, swing_low] = swing_detection(barsback)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

swing_high_price(_vw) =>
    _return=valuewhen(conf_swing_high, high[barsback],_vw)
swing_low_price(_vw) =>
    _return=valuewhen(conf_swing_low, low[barsback],_vw)
```